# Android Studio and Eclipse SDK pointing

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm working with both Android Studio and Eclipse both having their own SDK's in their respective folders. But it seems to me, Eclipse sometimes automatically starts pointing to my Android Studio SDK out of nowhere. Anyone have any clue ?

Comment: Why do you need different SDKs for Android Studio and Eclipse? One should be enough for both, unless you have both IDEs open at the same time. On topic: I haven't seen this issue, but I would guess that you update the Android Studio SDK more often and then Eclipse finds it as a newer one...

Comment: @helleye You maybe right, but I've encountered unusual errors having same SDK for both and then updating from either.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the Eclipse SDK path (window>preferences>Android). You might have more libraries in the list, and more locations, and I think Eclipse automatically search for SDK folder.

I have AS with SDK folder within, download/update SDK with AS, and Eclipse just pointing to the same folder. Errors that you've encountered could come from some confusion using/pointing/downloading different SDK stuff with two IDEs. So, put it simple.